# ubuntu python3 UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, encoding

I'm now encountered the following Error under ubuntu and python 3.4

Only one print with two Chinese unicode charaters.

```
root@vps3:~# python3 a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 1, in <module>
    print('\u4f60\u597d')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I can edit the Chinese characters through vim.

And I tried to check the python3 encoding:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
utf-8
```

It seemed ok.

What's the matter? Please help.

Comment: Works for me.  What's the encoding for stdout?  What's your locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that was because of the wrong file encoding.

The newly updated Pycharm IDE Under Windows changed the default encoding.

So my new code files encoding is turned to be GBK, which should be utf8.

And I changed the IDE setting, change the file encoding, everything is well.